# 『わかるPython』中のプログラムをターミナルから実行しようとするとSyntaxErrorとなります。

Tags: python, python3

上記の通りですがプログラムとターミナルをご提示します。

```
# coding: UTF-8

from sklearn import datasets, externals, linear_model, model_selection
import time

print('MNISTの取得：', end='', flush=True)
mnist = datasets.fetch_mldata('MNIST original', data_home='.')
data, label = mnist.data, mnist.target
print('完了')

TRAIN_SIZE = 600
TEST_SIZE = 100

t = model_selection.train_test_split(
    data, label, train_size=TRAIN_SIZE, test_size=TEST_SIZE)
train_data, test_data, train_label, test_label = t
print('訓練データ：', train_data.shape)
print('テストデータ：', test_data.shape)

print('学習：', end='', flush=True)
old = time.time()
model = linear_model.LogisticRegression().fit(train_data, train_label)
print(time.time()-old, '秒')

externals.joblib.dump(model, 'lr.model')

print('テスト結果：')
predict = model.predict(test_data)
count = [[0 for i in range(10)] for j in range(10)]
for i in range(TEST_SIZE):
    count[int(predict[i])][int(test_label[i])] += 1
print('正解   ', end='')
for i in range(10):
    print('   [{0}]'.format(i), end='')
print()
for i in range(10):
    print('予測[{0}]'.format(i), end='')
    for j in range(10):
        print('{0:6d}'.format(count[i][j]), end='')
    print()

print('正解率：', model.score(test_data, test_label)*100, '%')
```

ターミナルは以下の通りです。

```
ShouzounoiMac:WakaruPython syamaguchi$ python lr_train.py
  File "lr_train.py", line 6
    print('MNISTの取得：', end='', flush=True)
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

インターネットで調べてみましたがよくわかりません。お願いします。

Answer (score 2):

Python3.3より前のバージョンで実行しているからですかね。Python3.3以降を使って下さい。

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:36:49) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print('MNISTの取得：', end='', flush=True)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print('MNISTの取得：', end='', flush=True)
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print('MNISTの取得：', end='', flush=True)
MNISTの取得：>>>
```

参考
https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#print

> Changed in version 3.3: Added the flush keyword argument.

Comment: pythonは3.7なのですが。

Comment: `python3 lr_train.py`とか`python3.7 lr_train.py`で結果は変わりませんか？

Comment: python3 lr_train.pyで違った結果が出ましたが、ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peerというエラーになりました。

Comment: python3.7でも同じでした。

Comment: それはまた別の問題ですね。接続のトラブルでMNISTのデータ（`MNIST original.mat`）のダウンロードに失敗してるんだと思います。`MNIST original.mat`を適当なサイトから直接ダウンロードして、適切なディレクトリに置けば回避できると思います。